# Run unit tests and make unit test report available within jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Newbie to jenkins.
Experimenting to run unit tests (not even sure if the step to run is correct)
and also need to make a report available within jenkins (any suggestions how i can make this possible?)

```
pipeline {
agent any

stages 
{

    stage("Build") {
    
        steps {  
            echo 'Building the appication...'
          
        }
    }
    
    stage ('Unit test') {
    
        steps {     
                sh 'npm run test'
        }
    }
            
    stage ("Deploy") {
    
        steps {  
            echo 'Deploying the appication...'
        }
    }   
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use for example xunit tool (can be invoked on post actions or simply as step) to record a report from tests.

Here is the documentation:
https://plugins.jenkins.io/xunit/

To create a report with  npm run test command you have to define it in package.json of the project or wherever the command is defined

Rwmeber also to add `script {` after steps { in the stage where you call Bash script